# Oracle 11g ORA-01732 on Delete Query

Tags: oracle11g

I'm running into an issue with the below query. I found out how make the query work but I am still wondering why this ORA-01732. Below is the query that gives the error. The `CheckDate` function returns a date. If I `to_date` or `substring`  the denial date where it is `bolded` the query works. If I don't I get the error ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view. Does anyone know why it is saying I can't update a view when there is no view and why just by putting a `to_date` or `substring` it fixes the error?

```
DELETE FROM INPUT_STAGING I 
WHERE
( I.STATUS_IND = 'N'
AND (SUBSTR(I.PAYMENT_STATUS,1,1) = 'T'
    OR (NVL(TRIM(I.DENIAL_DT), '00000000') <> '00000000'
             AND codeowner.CheckDate(***I.DENIAL_DT***) < to_date('10/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')))
);
```

Comment: What data type is `i.denial_dt`?  Is that a `date`?  Or a `varchar2`?  What is the signature of `CheckDate`?  Does the function accept a `varchar2`?  Or a `date`?

Comment: The i.denial_dt is a varchar2. The CheckDate function accepts a nvarchar2.

Comment: What is the format of `denial_dt` and what is the definition of the `CheckDate` function?  I'm guessing that something about the `denial_dt` string is not in the format you expect when the error is thrown.  This is one of the (many) reasons that storing date values in `varchar2` columns is a headache.